# why Color Preview not displayed?

Tags: android, xml, colors, display, preview

I can see the color preview when hovering over the color name but the preview is not permanently displayed on the left side of the XML editor in Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1

i tried in android studio color xml layout , please any one who has a solution respond i thank you in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it is you are seeing and what it is you want to happen? Images/Screenshots will be appreciated.

Comment: color display preview   https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WcTl.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.